# find_all returns a limited list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use find_all to get a rather simple list of elements. No matter which parser I use it always gets a limited of elements containing anything useful and at some point all the next elements do not have any content although they clearly should. I have seen multiple posts where people had issues with it but it was always an empty list. I thought maybe it's because another part of the html is generated while scrolling down but it's not the case.

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/analityk%20danych;kw/warszawa;wp?rd=0'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='results')

job_elems = results.find_all('li', class_='results__list-container-item')

for job_elem in job_elems:
    #title_elem = job_elem.find('a', class_='offer-details__title-link')

    #company_elem = job_elem.find('a', class_='offer-company__name')
    #location_elem = job_elem.find('li' ,class_='offer-labels__item offer-labels__item--location')

    #if title_elem is None:
    #    continue

    #print(title_elem.text.strip())
    #print(company_elem.text.strip())
    #print(location_elem.text.strip())
    print()
    print(job_elem)
```

EDIT: Sorry for being unclear guys. As @TanmayaMeher suggests I did not paste any html as the link was available in the code and I guess it is easier to inspect.

The picture I provided was supposed to show the part of the output where the problem starts. Please see below a part of the output as a text. First paragraph is the last element that is parsed as I expect it and another lines are elements ('li' tag) that do not contain anything while I expect them to look like the correct one.

```
<li class="results__list-container-item">
<div class="offer offer--border offer--remoterecruitment">
<div class="offer__click">
<a class="offer__click-area" href="https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/chapter-lead-data-standardization-risk-area-warszawa,oferta,1000235456"></a>
</div>
<div class="offer__info">
<div class="offer-details">
<div class="offer-logo">
<a href="https://pracodawcy.pracuj.pl/company/20058995/profile"><img alt="logo" class="offer-logo__image" src="https://i.gpcdn.pl/oferty-loga-firm/wyniki-wyszukiwania/44864.png"/></a>
</div>
<div class="offer-details__text">
<h3 class="offer-details__title">
<a class="offer-details__title-link" href="https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/chapter-lead-data-standardization-risk-area-warszawa,oferta,1000235456">Chapter lead – Data Standardization (Risk Area)</a>
</h3>
<p class="offer-company">
<span class="offer-company__link-wrapper"></span>
<span class="offer-company__wrapper">
<a class="offer-company__name" href="https://pracodawcy.pracuj.pl/company/20058995/profile">ING Tech Poland</a>
</span>
</p>
</div>
<div class="offer-details__badge-wrap offer-details__badge-wrap--remoterecruitment">
<i class="mdi mdi-cellphone-message offer-details__badge-icon"></i>
<span class="offer-details__badge-name offer-details__badge-name--remoterecruitment">Rekrutacja zdalna</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="offer-labels__wrapper">
<ul class="offer-labels">
<li class="offer-labels__item offer-labels__item--location">
<i class="mdi mdi-map-marker offer-labels__item-icon"></i>Warszawa </li>
</ul>
<ul class="offer-labels">
<li class="offer-labels__item">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="offer-description">
<input class="offer-description__toggler" id="offer-description---cid-23435479" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="offer-description__toggler-label" for="offer-description---cid-23435479">
<i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down offer-description__toggler-icon"></i>
</label>
<div class="offer-description__content-wrap">
<span class="offer-description__content">
Must have You are open for other people and eager to take on new challenges, You are passionate about working with people and developing talents of others make you fulfilled, You prefer to concentrate on quality, innovation of created products...
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="offer-regions__port"></div>
<div class="offer-actions">
<span class="offer-actions__date">
<span class="offer-actions__date-long">opublikowana: </span>13 cze<span class="offer-actions__date-long">rwca</span> 2020
</span>
<div class="offer-actions__favs"></div>
</div>
</div>
</li>

<li class="results__list-container-item"></li>

<li class="results__list-container-item"></li>

<li class="results__list-container-item"></li>

<li class="results__list-container-item"></li>

<li class="results__list-container-item"></li>

<li class="results__list-container-item"></li>

<li class="results__list-container-item"></li>
```

Comment: What output do you get for the Sample/fragment you show? Please edit a complete parseable sample as text into the question and show what output you get and what you expect - I can’t paste a picture into a file and get BeautifulSoup to parse it.

Comment: “Complete” in the sense of valid html I can parse - please make it minimal to show the problem, i.e. not a massive page of data

Comment: @barny the url is in the code. He pasted from line 845 onwards as little sample (as image lol like everybody does) . The [LINK here to source](view-source:https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/analityk%20danych;kw/warszawa;wp?rd=0) .Though i still don't understand what he/she wants?!

Comment: Yeah don’t want to wade through a non-minimal example - that’s just saving the OP work at the expense of anyone (not me!) who might try to reproduce and fix the problem. And still need to see what output is produced vs what is expected.

Comment: I edited the original post answering your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The data is embedded in the page in the form of JavaScript `window.__INITIAL_STATE__` variable. You can parse it with `re`/`json` module.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/analityk%20danych;kw/warszawa;wp?rd=0'
html_text = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads( re.search(r'window\.__INITIAL_STATE__ = (.*?\});', html_text).group(1) )

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data to screen:
for offer in data['offers']:
    print('{:<10}{:<80}{}'.format(offer['commonOfferId'], offer['jobTitle'], offer['employer']))
```

Prints:

```
23433957  Senior Business Intelligence Analyst w Zespole Data Intelligence Solutions      KPMG
23436174  Quantitative Associate (Model Validation)                                       ING Tech Poland
23436175  Data Analyst (Risk Modelling) (Risk Hub)                                        ING Tech Poland
23436664  Reports Developer (VBA)                                                         Randstad Polska Sp. z o.o.
23440135  Firmwide Data Management - Data Integration - Change Project Lead – Associate   J.P. Morgan Poland Services sp. z o.o.
23440182  Treasury – Product Control (P&L and Risk) Analyst                               J.P. Morgan Poland Services sp. z o.o.
23441295  Brand Reporting Manager                                                         JTI Polska sp. z o.o.

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrej! What's the mechanism behind the fact that I am able to retrieve a few elements parsing it as a usual html? Also how do you know at the first glance you should check if the data is embedded in form of JavaScript?